# HLSL XNA texture positioning

Tags: model, xna, textures, hlsl

I want to put a texture on a certain spot on my model. And i don´t know if i need to do this in HLSL or my xna project. And how i could do this. Can anybody put me on the right track?

edit: What i want to create is a functionallity so i can load a texture (like a logo) and put it on a car. So i need to set the position(probaly in hlsl). i want to draw it over the excisting model. I know the mesh on which i want to put it. and can put a texture to the selected mesh. But i want to draw the texture on a certain part of that mesh and not over the whole mesh

Comment: The name of the technique I think you're looking for is "**decaling**" - you're adding a "decal". Appropriately enough, that's also what you would call it if you did it to a real car.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easiest to do this through the modeling program. Get the model looking how you want it then simply load is up and draw it as the [MSDN tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197293%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx) instruct.

Comment: I know how that works :p
What i want to create is a functionallity so i can load a texture (like a logo) and put it on a car. So i need to set the position(probaly in hlsl). i want to draw it over the excisting model.
I know the mesh on which i want to put it. and can put a texture to the selected mesh. But i want to draw the texture on a certain part of that mesh and not over the whole mesh

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to alter the texture by using a RenderTarget.

Comment: can you specify this a little bit more for me. because i don't really get what you mean.

Comment: are there some examples of this because i can't find them

Comment: is there a way i can get create a texture for a mesh. because my mesh i want to edit is colored and not textured.

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/mikebmcl/archive/2011/02/18/xna-rendertarget2d-sample.aspx